# Hide/show buttons in the table on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in web and need your help. I have such table:

```
<table class="table" id="requestTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Start Date
            </th>
            <th>
                End Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Approved
            </th>
            <th>
                Employee
            </th>      
            <th>
                Position
            </th>                  
            <th class="no-sort">

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.DateStart.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DateEnd.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td data-name="@item.Id">
                    @item.Approved.ToString()
                </td>                
                <td>
                    @item.FirstName.ToString() @item.LastName.ToString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Position.ToString()
                </td>

                 <td>                    
                        <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="@item.Id">Accept </button>                  

                        <button class="btn btn-danger decline-button" data-id="@item.Id">Decline</button>                                                         
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I have JQuery script for this `.cshtml` page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   // $('td[data-approved==True]').nextAll('td').find('button.accept-button').hide();
    //$('td[data-name="' + "True" + '"]').find('button.accept-button').hide();
    //$('td[data-approved!=True]').nextAll('td').find('button.decline-button').hide();    
    $('#requestTable').DataTable(
        {
            aoColumns: [
            { mDataProp: "DateStart", sTitle: "Date Start" },
            { mDataProp: "DateEnd", sTitle: "Date End" },
            { mDataProp: "Approved", sTitle: "Approved" },
            { mDataProp: "Data", sTitle: "Employee" },
            { mDataProp: "Position", sTitle: "Position" },
            { mDataProp: "", sTitle: "" }
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 'no-sort',
                orderable: false
            }]
        });

    $('button.accept-button').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
        var appr = $('td[data-name="' + id + '"]');
        appr[0].textContent = "True";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TableRequest/AcceptRequest",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
        $(this).hide();
    });
    var tempId;
    $('button.decline-button').click(function () {
        tempId = $(this).attr('data-id')
        $("#dialog").dialog()
        var appr = $('td[data-name="' + tempId + '"]');
        appr[0].textContent = "False";
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('button.ok-request').click(function () {
        var message = $('textarea#commentForDecline').val();        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TableRequest/DeclineRequest",
            data: { 'message': message, 'id': tempId },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });   
        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        $('textarea#commentForDecline').val('');        
    });
});
```

Value `Approved` in the table can be `true` or `false`. As you can see I have two buttons in my table: Accept button and Decline button for each row. I need:

- 1) When page was load, if `Approved == false` show `accept button`
  for this row and hide `decline`, else - show `decline button` and
  hide `accept button`.
- 2) On `accept button` click I need to hide    `accept button` and
  show `decline button` for this row only. On    `decline button`
  click, I need to hide `decline button` and show    `accept button`
  for this row only. May anyone help me? I know that it    simple, but,
  to my shame, can't do this .

Comment: If you want a cleaner answer try mine.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) When page was load, if Approved == false show accept button for this row and hide decline, else - show decline button and hide accept button.

```
 <td>                    
<button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="@item.Id" style='@Html.Raw(item.Approved == False?"":"display:none")'>Accept </button>                  
<button class="btn btn-danger decline-button" data-id="@item.Id" style='@Html.Raw(item.Approved == False?"display:none":"")'>Decline</button>                                                         
 </td>
```

2) On accept button click I need to hide  accept button and show decline button for this row only. On  decline button click, I need to hide decline button and show  accept button for this row only. May anyone help me? I know that it simple, but, to my shame, can't do this .

```
 $('button.accept-button').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
        var appr = $('td[data-name="' + id + '"]');
        appr[0].textContent = "True";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TableRequest/AcceptRequest",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
        $(this).hide();
        **//ADD THIS TO SHOW DECLINE BUTTON**
        $(this).parent().find('button.decline-button').show();
    });


 $('button.decline-button').click(function () {
        tempId = $(this).attr('data-id')
        $("#dialog").dialog()
        var appr = $('td[data-name="' + tempId + '"]');
        appr[0].textContent = "False";
        $(this).hide();
        **// ADD THIS TO SHOW ACCEPT BUTTON**
        $(this).parent().find('button.accept-button').show();
    });
```

Comment: @Alexander - No Worries :)

Answer (score 2):

For the initial button display, wrap then in an `if` block and a `style="display:none"`

```
<td>
  @if(item.Approved)
  {                 
    <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="@item.Id" style="display:none">Accept </button>                  
    <button class="btn btn-danger decline-button" data-id="@item.Id">Decline</button>
  }
  else
  {
    <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="@item.Id">Accept </button>                  
    <button class="btn btn-danger decline-button" data-id="@item.Id" style="display:none">Decline</button>
  }                                                     
</td>
```

and to toggle the visbility

```
$('button.accept-button').click(function () {
  ....
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('td').children('button').last().show();
});

$('button.decline-button').click(function () {
  ....
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('td').children('button').first().show();
});
```

Side notes:

1. It should be `tempId = $(this).data('id')` not `tempId =
   $(this).attr('data-id')`
2. Its not clear why you would need `<td data-name="@item.Id">` or `var
   appr = $('td[data-name="' + tempId + '"]');` since you know the
   value because you clicked on the respective button (in the
   'decline' button, the value must already be `true'` and vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, rather simple to code, don't need two click events...

Simplified the HTML so I could test it in Fiddle, but you should be able to get the idea...

I simplified the html in the Fiddle and also left out parts like the ajax that I'm sure you can figure out on your own.

Click for Fiddle
  [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/mkgpLx2e/1/)

```
       <td>                    
           <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="5">Accept </button>                                                                            
       </td>

       <td>                    
           <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="10">Accept </button>                                                                           
       </td>                

       <td>                    
           <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="15">Accept </button>                                                                             
       </td>



   (function($){

    $(function(){  //document.ready


        $.each($('button.accept-button'), function(i,v) {


           //run your checks and set the button to decline if need be...
            var thisid = $(this).data('id');
            if (thisid == '10') {

                  $(this).html('Decline');
                  $(this).addClass('decline');
            }
        });

        $('button').on('click', function() {

            if ($(this).hasClass('decline')) {
               $(this).removeClass('decline');
               $(this).html('Accept');
            } else {
               $(this).addClass('decline');
               $(this).html('Decline');
            }



        });

  });

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: O, thanks for idea! So, as I understand, it's possible to change css class on button click. Am I right?

Comment: yeah, see jquery addClass, removeClass, and hasClass